# How can I read a text file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I read a `.txt` file in Javascript? I have a folder name and need to load the file present in the folder (there is only one). For example, if I have a folder called `folder1` it contains 3 same txt files with different name and other files also present in that folder1 I need to read only one txt file any one.

Comment: Welcome to SO! *Send me code* -questions are frowned upon here. It's more likely get some answers if you show some effort and post what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "http://my.remote.url/myremotefile.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
 if (txtFile.readyState === 4)   // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
 {
  if (txtFile.status === 200)   // Makes sure it's found the file.
   {
    allText = txtFile.responseText; 
   }
 }
}
```

if the files are on he client computer there could be a problem cause of security reasons i dont that it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This website is not here to do the job for you!

but, i'll point you the right way,

you can list the files in this folder and look for files with .txt extentions..

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assuming a text file full of integers
var fileArray = []
var file_selector = document.getElementById("file_selector");

file_selector.addEventListener("change", function(){
    var files_array = this.files;
//Now you have a reference to the file and you can do something with it.     
   var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(this.files[0]); 
    type = "text";

    reader.onload = function(){
        array = reader.result.split(/\n/); 

        for (a in array) {
            //now turn your strings into integers
            array[a] = parseInt(array[a], 10); 
        }

        //Check your new array
        for (var k = 0; k< array.length; k++){
            console.log(array[k]);
        }

    }

});
```